# Ordenando Aniversariantes - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Boa noite!

tenho um Banco de dados SQL Server com campos: Nome e Data Nascimento.

Preciso ordenar pela Data Nascimento, sendo a ordem da data mais próxima para a data mais distante, a intenção nesse ordenamento é saber os próximos aniversariantes até o próximo ano (tendo como base a data atual).
Já tentei alguns SELECTs, porém todos ordenam considerando o Ano de nascimento.

1. Select * from TabelaX ORDER By Aniversario DESC ou ASC
2. Select * from TabelaX ORDER BY DAY(Aniversario), MONTH(Aniversario)
3. Select * from TabelaX ORDER By datediff(month,getdate(), Aniversario) ASC ou DESC

Agradeço antecipadamente pela ajuda.

Comment: acho que precisa de um `where` ai

Comment: @RicardoPontual, já testei também, mas não funcionou. Agradeço sua sugestão.

Comment: *"tendo como base a data atual"* e como vai filtrar isso se não for usando `where`? primeiro filtre  isso *"os próximos aniversariantes até o próximo ano"*, só depois ordene

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual, desculpe-me acabei não informado, comecei a estudar SQL, ontem, tudo que consegui fazer foi pesquisando muito, mas ainda não consegui montar a lógica com o SQL. Agradeço, continuarei na trilha da pesquisa.

Answer (score 0):

Se forem apenas os aniversários que acontecerão daqui para a frente tente:

```
SELECT * FROM TabelaX 
WHERE MONT(Aniversario) * 100 + DAY(Aniversario) > MONTH(getdate()) * 100 + DAY(getdate()) 
ORDER BY MONTH(Aniversario), DAY(Aniversario)
```

Comment: os que já fizeram também devem aparecer, ou seja, serão os primeiros da lista.

Comment: Se consegui entender então tire a cláusula WHERE.

Comment: agradeço mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

No artigo [Dominando datas e horas no SQL Server](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2020/02/29/dominando-datas-horas/) você encontra informações sobre como manipular datas no SQL Server, inclusive com um item tratando justamente de relação de aniversariantes. Desse artigo copiei o seguinte código T-SQL:

```
-- código #4.22 v2
-- emite relação de aniversariantes dos próximos dias
--
-- Autor: José Diz 
-- Publicado em: Porto SQL - https://portosql.wordpress.com/blog/

-- informa quantidade de dias
declare @NDias tinyint;
set @NDias= 15;

-- gera datas com limites do período de emissão
declare @Amanha date, @Ate date;
set @Amanha= dateadd (day, +1, cast (sysdatetime() as date));
set @Ate= dateadd (day, (@NDias -1), @Amanha);

-- obtém ano inicial e ano final
declare @Ano_I int, @Ano_F int;
set @Ano_I= year (@Amanha);
set @Ano_F= year (@Ate);

--
IF (@Ano_I = @Ano_F)
  -- período de emissão no mesmo ano
  SELECT Nome, convert (char(5), Data_nasc, 103) as [Dia/Mês]
    from dbo.Cadastro
    where dateadd (year,   
                   (@Ano_I - year (Data_nasc)),
                   Data_nasc) between @Amanha and @Ate
    order by month (Data_nasc), day (Data_nasc)

else
  -- período de emissão cruza ano
  SELECT Nome, convert (char(5), Data_nasc, 103) as [Dia/Mês]
    from dbo.Cadastro
    where dateadd (year,    
                   (@Ano_I - year (Data_nasc)),
                   Data_nasc) >= @Amanha
          or dateadd (year,    
                      (@Ano_F - year (Data_nasc)),
                      Data_nasc) <= @Ate
    order by dateadd (year, (@Ano_I - year (Data_nasc), Data_nasc);
```

.

O que o código T-SQL faz é trazer a data de nascimento para o ano corrente (ou ano seguinte, se o período envolve mais de um ano) e então comparar com as datas que delimitam o período.

No código SQL original não havia ordenação. Acrescentei-a nesta resposta mas não testei; espero que esteja correto.